# Direct Mapping Cache

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

Consider the cache system with the following properties:
Cache (direct mapped cache):
- Cache size 128 bytes, block size 16 bytes (24 bytes)
- Tag/Valid bits for cache blocks are as follows:

```
Block index - 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Tag         - 0 6 7 0 5 3 1 3
Valid       - 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Find Tag Block index, Block offset, Cache hit/miss for memory addresses - 0x7f6, 0x133.

I am not sure how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Since cache size is 128 bytes, cache has 128/16 = 8 blocks and hence block offset = 3.

Since block size is 16 bytes, block offset is 4.

Address bits are 12 for `0x7f6 = 0111 1111 0110`:

```
Offset = (0110 >> 1) = 3
Index  = 111 = 7
Tag    = 01111 = f
```